# How do I display Greek characters in Android?

Tags: android

How do I display Greek characters in Android?

Comment: In what context, eg: a math app, or L10N?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android has full Unicode support and displaying Greek characters should be very easy. In your strings.xml file you can use Greek characters and these will be displayed correctly. Of course you need to save your file in UTF-8 format.

Comment: Or use escapes: <string name="foo">This is alpha: \u0391</string>