# Possible characters in android

Tags: android, fonts, character

is there a way I can determine which characters are possible in android's textview ?!

I want to display some fancy characters in android like those:

ƬΉIƧ IƧ Λ ƧΛMPᄂΣ ƬΣXƬ. ЩЯIƬΣ YӨЦЯ MΣƧƧΛGΣ IП ƬΉIƧ ƬΣXƬ BӨX.

But somehow, android can't display all of them. Is there a way to get a list of all characters in android ?!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3941587/646391 check this.

Comment: This doesn't work. When I use flipped text: 0687954321zʎxʌnʇsɹbdoɯןʞظıɥbɟǝpɔqɐzʎxʌnʇsɹbdouɯןʞظıɥbɟǝpɔqɐ   I get a rectangular box instead of the flipped character